# Dissimilar hardware server restore with Acronis

Tags: windows, backup, windows-server-2008, acronis-trueimage

I have a backup of a Dell PowerEdge 2950 (500GB, 2 partitions) server created with Acronis Advanced Server 11.5 which I'm trying to restore on a new HP ProLiant ML310e Gen8 (1TB-RAID1) using **Universal Restore**. I've integrated the [theses](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/service_packs/en/index.html) drivers into the Acronis Boot Media.

The restore was successful but when I start the server it's unable to boot from the C:\ drive. When I check the disk through the Acronis Rescue Media (Disk Management) both partitions are marked as primary.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Raymond, we're doing some cleanup of manufacturer meta tags, and your question is the last one with the [acronis] tag.  The tag refers specifically to True Image.  There were a number of questions referring to other Acronis products.  This is the only one specifically about Backup and Recovery so I'm hesitant to create a tag just for this question.  I went ahead and changed it to the dedicated [acronis-trueimage] tag, figuring the question and future readers will be best served with a popular, similar tag.  Please holler if you would prefer to handle this a different way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Raymond**, thank you for sharing your experiences with Acronis Backup and Recovery 11,5 Advanced Server for Windows.

My name is Anna Trifonova and I'm writing you on behalf of Acronis Customer Central.

As far as I understand you've recovered your system using Acronis Universal Restore function http://kb.acronis.com/content/35681, but after successful restore the system is unbootable.

The most probable reason for it is usage of wrong drivers.

Please follow this guide http://www.acronis.com/support/documentation/ABR11.5/#16428.html to troubleshoot bootability and repair your system. Acronis Universal Restore can be applied after recovery to the operating system that already exists on the machine as well.

Let me know if you have additional questions.

Best regards,

Anna Trifonova

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. I'll try the approach suggested and let you know.

Comment: Hi Anna,
I did tried the various solutions up to installing a copy of the OS and starting the Recovery from it but it always failed when rebooting unable to find the Boot partition. 
Also the ASRM is not able to be installed successfully, i guess it  has somethiing to do with the iLO software of the server.